# db_owner permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently limiting permissions of some *database users*.

The issue is this, Once I remove ***db_owner*** permission from some users,they no longer have access to execute stored procedures.

How do you grant permission to a database user to be able to execute *stored procedure* without making the user a ***db_owner*** ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Product specific issue...)

Comment: Grant `EXECUTE` permission to this user

Comment: `GRANT EXECUTE ON YourProc TO User`

Comment: There is no `db_owner` permission in standard SQL.

Comment: @jarlh Microsoft sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `SQL Server`, you can just grant the `EXECUTE` permission to this user as:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON YourProc TO User;
```

Btw, [*db_owner*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017) is a `database ROLE` in `SQL Server`, not a permission.

For more information visit [GRANT Object Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax)

Comment: Or if you want the user to execute all current and future stored procedures and scalar-valued functions:`grant execute on schema::dbo to User` for a single schema, or just `grant execute to User` for the whole database.